Superset Invalid Login Issue while Implementing SSO
I am having a superset running in AWS EC2 instance using docker compose. While I am doing docker compose up the server gets up and I can see server running. Additionally I have configured an SSO for Microsoft for the superset to login.
So the flow will be A user comes to login page of superset enter its Microsoft credential it authenticates and redirect it to inside superset.
But in my case it is authenticates user and redirect to login page and says Invalid login. Please try again.
While my superset_app container logs says
werkzeug.exceptions.NotFound: 404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server.
Linked is my superset logs image.
Here is the superset_config.py file
import logging
import os

from celery.schedules import crontab
from flask_caching.backends.filesystemcache import FileSystemCache

logger = logging.getLogger()

DATABASE_DIALECT = os.getenv("DATABASE_DIALECT")
DATABASE_USER = os.getenv("DATABASE_USER")
DATABASE_PASSWORD = os.getenv("DATABASE_PASSWORD")
DATABASE_HOST = os.getenv("DATABASE_HOST")
DATABASE_PORT = os.getenv("DATABASE_PORT")
DATABASE_DB = os.getenv("DATABASE_DB")

EXAMPLES_USER = os.getenv("EXAMPLES_USER")
EXAMPLES_PASSWORD = os.getenv("EXAMPLES_PASSWORD")
EXAMPLES_HOST = os.getenv("EXAMPLES_HOST")
EXAMPLES_PORT = os.getenv("EXAMPLES_PORT")
EXAMPLES_DB = os.getenv("EXAMPLES_DB")

# The SQLAlchemy connection string.
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = (
    f"{DATABASE_DIALECT}://"
    f"{DATABASE_USER}:{DATABASE_PASSWORD}@"
    f"{DATABASE_HOST}:{DATABASE_PORT}/{DATABASE_DB}"
)

SQLALCHEMY_EXAMPLES_URI = (
    f"{DATABASE_DIALECT}://"
    f"{EXAMPLES_USER}:{EXAMPLES_PASSWORD}@"
    f"{EXAMPLES_HOST}:{EXAMPLES_PORT}/{EXAMPLES_DB}"
)

REDIS_HOST = os.getenv("REDIS_HOST", "redis")
REDIS_PORT = os.getenv("REDIS_PORT", "6379")
REDIS_CELERY_DB = os.getenv("REDIS_CELERY_DB", "0")
REDIS_RESULTS_DB = os.getenv("REDIS_RESULTS_DB", "1")

RESULTS_BACKEND = FileSystemCache("/app/superset_home/sqllab")

CACHE_CONFIG = {
    "CACHE_TYPE": "RedisCache",
    "CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT": 300,
    "CACHE_KEY_PREFIX": "superset_",
    "CACHE_REDIS_HOST": REDIS_HOST,
    "CACHE_REDIS_PORT": REDIS_PORT,
    "CACHE_REDIS_DB": REDIS_RESULTS_DB,
}
DATA_CACHE_CONFIG = CACHE_CONFIG


class CeleryConfig:
    broker_url = f"redis://{REDIS_HOST}:{REDIS_PORT}/{REDIS_CELERY_DB}"
    imports = (
        "superset.sql_lab",
        "superset.tasks.scheduler",
        "superset.tasks.thumbnails",
        "superset.tasks.cache",
    )
    result_backend = f"redis://{REDIS_HOST}:{REDIS_PORT}/{REDIS_RESULTS_DB}"
    worker_prefetch_multiplier = 1
    task_acks_late = False
    beat_schedule = {
        "reports.scheduler": {
            "task": "reports.scheduler",
            "schedule": crontab(minute="*", hour="*"),
        },
        "reports.prune_log": {
            "task": "reports.prune_log",
            "schedule": crontab(minute=10, hour=0),
        },
    }


CELERY_CONFIG = CeleryConfig

FEATURE_FLAGS = {"ALERT_REPORTS": True}
ALERT_REPORTS_NOTIFICATION_DRY_RUN = True
# When using docker compose baseurl should be http://superset_app:8088/
# The base URL for the email report hyperlinks.
SQLLAB_CTAS_NO_LIMIT = True

#
# Optionally import superset_config_docker.py (which will have been included on
# the PYTHONPATH) in order to allow for local settings to be overridden
#
try:
    import superset_config_docker
    from superset_config_docker import *  # noqa

    logger.info(
        f"Loaded your Docker configuration at " f"[{superset_config_docker.__file__}]"
    )
except ImportError:
    logger.info("Using default Docker config...")

# Ensure you are using HTTPS
ENABLE_PROXY_FIX = True
PREFERRED_URL_SCHEME = 'https'
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = "Lax"

#SSO Login
from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_OAUTH
from custom_sso_security_manager import CustomSsoSecurityManager

# Set the authentication type to OAuth
AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OAUTH

# Will allow user self registration, allowing to create Flask users from Authorized User
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True

# The default user self registration role
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "Public"
CUSTOM_SECURITY_MANAGER = CustomSsoSecurityManager

OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [{
   'name': 'SSO',
   'token_key': 'access_token',
   'icon': 'fa-windows',
   'remote_app':{
        'api_base_url': 'https://login.microsoft.com/tenant_id/oauth2',
        'request_token_url': None,
        'request_token_params': {
                'scope': 'openid profile email'
        },
        'access_token_url': 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_id/oauth2/v2.0/token',
        'acess_token_params':{
                'scope': 'openid profile email'
        },
        'authorize_url': 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_id/oauth2/v2.0/authorize',
        'authorize_params':{
                'scope': 'openid profile email'
        },
        'client_id': 'client-id(application-id)',
        'client_secret': 'secret-key',
        'jwks_uri': 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys',
        'redirect_uri': 'https://superset.domain.com/oauth-authorize/callback'
   }
}]

OAUTH_USER_INFO_URL = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me'

from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_OAUTH

def get_oauth_user_info(response):
    user_info = response.json()

    # Assign role based on domain
    if user_info['mail'].endswith('@domain.com'):
        return {
            'role': 'Admin',
            'user_info': user_info
        }
    else:
        return {
            'role': 'Public',
            'user_info': user_info
        }

So I have tried various steps like :

Checking my application(client) id
Checking my secrete keys
Checking Config file.

Finally found that it's an open issue on the GitHub of Superset repo also tried the solution present in the comments.
I followed all the steps as it is along with the docker-compose.yaml code from this official documentation but no luck

You need to follow instruction in https://superset.apache.org/docs/configuration/configuring-superset/#custom-oauth2-configuration
And need more customize in CustomSsoSecurityManager function
You must check user from  self.find_user and after that use login_user for login
